# Reaching azure VM thro ip-adress?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using terraform to build up an infastructure. I've built up a virtual machine with terraform which says on azure that it is running and has a public ip. However I can't seem to reach the VM by searching for the ip in my webbrowser. Is there something wrong in my code or what am i missing? Below shows the terraform code which creates the VM.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "myterraformvm" {
name                  = "myVM"
location              = "westeurope"
resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.myterraformnic.id}"]
vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myOsDisk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
}

storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04.0-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
}

os_profile {
    computer_name  = "myvm"
    admin_username = "azureuser"
}

os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = true
    ssh_keys {
        path     = "/home/azureuser/.ssh/authorized_keys"
        key_data = "ssh-rsa here is a valid SSH key in my original code"
    }
}

 boot_diagnostics {
    enabled = "true"
    storage_uri = "${azurerm_storage_account.mystorageaccount.primary_blob_endpoint}"
}

tags {
    environment = "Igaaas"
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a web server running in your image? Have you allowed port 80 in the firewall in the OS? Have you added the Network Security Group rule to allow port 80 access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, If you want to use your webbrowser to access the Azure VM via the public IP. You need to have a web server in your VM and listen to a port.

For example, you have a web server in the VM and listen to port 80, so you can use your webbrowser to access the VM via vm_puvlicIP:80.

I see you set ssh key in the code. If you want to ssh your VM, you should have an ssh tool. Then you can use the ssh tool to connect your Ubuntu via the public IP and the ssh key.

For Terraform, it's just a tool used to create the resources, such as VM. Like Azure template.

Comment: How do I put up this webserver in my VM with terraform? I have added network rule allowing http connection.

Comment: You can follow this example: [terraform-web-server](https://github.com/dokadon/terraform-web-server). It will help you a favor.